# Good Dynamics support for swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, blackberry, xcode8, good-dynamics

I'm trying to implement Good Dynamics for iOS. I want to know if anyone uses it frequently.. although it's made by blackberry but they haven't provided support for swift 3 yet nor swift 2.3.
Only swift 2.0 is supported.

So has any one tested it or can someone suggest me alternative or is there any work around for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well as it turns out. Their library is working with **Swift 3 and Swift 3.1,** I used `URLSession` to make/get my http request and responses.

I can confirm that SDK versions **BlackBerry_Dynamics_SDK_for_iOS_v3.1.0.405 and BlackBerry_Dynamics_SDK_for_iOS_v3.0.2.51** are working.

**UPDATE:
It also works with Swift 3.1**

Comment: Hi Umar,
I am not able to get/downlod file using URLSession. Could you able to give us some pointer on this?